# how do i get my run length encoding script to still fuction after 10 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have a program

```
def encode(s):
    counts = {}
    for c in s:
        if counts.get(c) is None:
            counts[c] = s.count(c)
    return "".join(k+str(v) for k,v in counts.items())

def decode(s):
    return "".join((map(lambda tup:  tup[0] * int(tup[1]), zip(s[0:len(s):2], s[1:len(s):2]))))
```

the thing is, if i were to run encode('aaaaaaaaaa') which is 10 a's, i get 'a10', which is what i want. but when i use decode('a10'), it just returns 'a'. this boggles my mind and i cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: `zip(s[0:len(s):2], s[1:len(s):2])` with this you're assuming that every even index in the encoded string is a letter & every odd index is the integer. Which is not the case for `a10`

Comment: how would i edit this?

Comment: Is doing it in one line a restriction?  If not, I would personally write a for loop, keeping track of a couple of state variables: an integer buffer and the letter being used (so after I have read in `'a1'`, then the buffer would = `'1'` and the letter would be `'a'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your decode function works with single digit repetition only.

For example, `'a9'` will be decoded correctly.
With `'a10'`, what is happening is that it gets to repeat `'a'` only once for the `1` in `10`. Decoding `a20` will cause `a` to be repeated twice, and the same for `a200`.

---

One way to solve the problem is to write a generator that handles multi-char numbers appropriately (of course numbers cannot be encoded), e.g.:

```
def get_char_len_pair(s):
    ch = None
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit():
            n += c
        else:
            if ch is not None:
                yield ch, int(n)
            ch = c
            n = ''
    if ch is not None:
        yield ch, int(n)
```

and use that in your `str.join()` call:

```
def decode(s):
    return "".join((map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], get_char_len_pair(s))))


decode('a20b10')
# 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb'
```